# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'v'

Tags: php, regex, warnings, preg-match, modifier

I keep getting this error about 20 times in my wordpress blog about the same line of code. Here is the line of code that keeps getting the error.

```
if ( preg_match( '/' . $id_base . '-([0-9]+)$/', $widget_id, $matches ) )
        $number = max($number, $matches[1]);
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex will break if the string `$id_base` has a `/` in it as you are using `/` as the regex delimiter.

To fix this use `preg_quote` on `$id_base` as:

```
if (preg_match('/'. preg_quote($id_base,'/').'-([0-9]+)$/', .....) {
```

Comment: so use 'preg_quote' instead of '$id_base'?
how would you rewrite the line?

Comment: @Frank: My answer has the usage.

Comment: whoops, sorry didnt see it. LOL